# C# HTTP Headers crafting

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, spoofing

Since Http Headers can be crafted and customize, how would I change or modify the IP part of it using C# 's HttpWebRequest class. In other words, how can IP Spoofing be done using C#.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you give more detalis? The IP layer is much lower than the Http layer.

Comment: I'm sorry. Here's more info:
So since the IP address of my client is sent along with the rest of my GET packet, how would I change it? 
From what I've heard, I can change the origin IP of a packet, and the disadvantage would be that I wouldn't be getting anything back, which is fine by me.

Comment: Sorry, but Raj was right - IP Is a lot lower, you can not change the IP packet's return address in the HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can I ask why you need that ? Looks for hacking purposes. Anyway if it is not for hacking may be we can find another solution without replacing IP.

Comment: Actually, it's for a school project. Our instructor has set up a server with a simple php script that records IP addresses of visits and we're supposed to post our student number as an IP. I see no solution except spoofing IPs, but I welcome any suggestions.
Just curious, but I don't see how one would use this to hack? I mean, there's absolutely no advantage over using proxies since you don't get any information back.

Comment: Please check here : http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2015.htm
This must be helpful although the code is in VB, but you can figure that out. And here in C# :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/cstcpipwmi.aspx. But please note that as already mentioned in comments by Raj and TomTom this is not in HTTP level.